# Grafana aliases for multiples of $__interval

Tags: grafana

I want to make a Grafana dashboard with multiple dynamic interval graphs of the same time series. However I want the current intervals to be displayed in the graph legend.
[image]
Obviously the multiplication doesn't work in the alias field. Is there any way to have it calculated in the alias?

I've tried naively multiplying it in the alias field and did some googling on dynamic alias calculation, but didn't find anything

Comment: `$__interval` is is string, e.g. `10m` - how can you multiply string with integer?

Comment: @JanGaraj that's a demo to show what I'm trying to accomplish